# Microsoft access project (ADP) in access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

I would like to make an access application that ms access is FE and sql server is BE, what i remember in access 2003 there was access project file could do this job. 
I read in some where in google there is not ADP in new version of ms access. 
Please help
 is there any way yet to do Ms access as a FE and sql server as a BE?

Is there ADP yet?

If there is not ADP yet , what is the replacement way for doing this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not.

The usual method to connect (link) tables and views from SQL Server (and other engines like MySQL) is via ODBC.